# XPath for elements with attributes

Tags: java, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Forms>
<Form ID="533" PhysDocID=""
    TemplateID="616">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
        <TextField1 ind="3" />
        <NumOfCigar ind="0" />
        <Check1 ind="0">0</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="1">1</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="2">2</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="3">3</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="4">4</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="5">5</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="6">6</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="7">7</Check1>
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
<Form ID="533" PhysDocID=""
    TemplateID="989">
    <topmostSubform ind="0">
    <Check1 ind="0">0</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="1">1</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="2">2</Check1>
        <Check1 ind="3">3</Check1>
    </topmostSubform>
</Form>
```

I want to get the element check1 with attribute "ind" = 3 inside the Form which have "TemplateID" = 616.

So far i can find the element but without the attribute condition:

```
String xpath = "//" + root + "//" + pNodeName + "[@"+ pAttributeName+"='" + pAttributeValue + "']"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the Kiss route....:

```
String xpath = "/Forms/Form[@TemplateID='616']/Check1[@ind='3']"
```

Comment: You omitted `topmostSubForm`. This should work just fine `/Forms/Form[@TemplateID='616']/topmostSubform/Check1[@ind='3']`